# How can I place an image next to text box horizontally?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to replicate this layout in the screenshot below by placing an image next to text box horizontally. Numbers three and four are images, six and five are text.

For the text should I use?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1> 
    <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing
    responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p> 
  </div>
  <p>This is some text.</p> 
  <p>This is another text.</p> 
</div>
```

After I have to text in the correct place how can I place an image to the left of it like on the diagram below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using bootstrap, so put the rows and columns to good use:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4"> Image box 3</div>
    <div class="col-xl-8"> Text box 6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4"> Image box 4</div>
    <div class="col-xl-8"> Text box 5</div>
</div>
```

for more information on the grid system that bootstrap uses:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: well it's just example code, not meant for copy-paste. What exactly doesn't work?